# Angular Testing: Get HTML Element inside child component that uses ng-content

Tags: angular, testing, jasmine, karma-runner, ng-bootstrap

I have a problem writing unit tests for a component that uses [ngb-accordion](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/accordion/examples) to display its content. In this case, the accordion is only used for styling purposes, but I use it to provide design consitency across the app.

The most simplest template I could come up with to show the error:

```html
<ngb-accordion #acc="ngbAccordion" activeIds="sample">
  <ngb-panel id="sample">
    <ng-template ngbPanelContent>
      <p class="myClass">Some Text</p> <!-- I want to access this element -->
    </ng-template>
  </ngb-panel>
</ngb-accordion>
```

The testcase looks as follows:

```
it('should find my element', () => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LoginComponent);

    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const p = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.myClass')).nativeElement;
    p.id;
});
```

which throws an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of null
```

Here is the `beforeEach` for my test:

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ LoginComponent, NgbAccordion ],
      providers : [FormBuilder, ...]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));
```

(where `LoginComponent` is the tested Component).

I dont think it has something to do with `ng-template`, as with the following html, the element is found correctly:

```html
<div *ngIf="false else always">Should not show</div>

<ng-template #always>
  <p class="myClass">Some Text</p>
</ng-template>
```

I don't know why it doesn't work with `ngbAccordion`, could it be a timing issue? As I am not mocking the `NgbAccordion` class (and I dont want to!), I expect it's contents to be rendered correctly. Is it, because the html is probably rendered with 'ng-content' from within the 'NgbAccordion'? If so, what could I do to access my element?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using onPush change detection mechanism in the Component?

Comment: no, nothing of the sort. the component (.ts) could be empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sometimes happens to me too when it's inside of foreign elements like that.

Instead of `query` try going straight to the `nativeElement` or using `document.querySelector`.

```
 const p = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('.myClass');
 console.log(p); // see if it returns
 const p2 = document.querySelector('.myClass');
 console.log(p2); // see if it returns
```

If that doesn't work, inspect the `nativeElement` and ensure the element is there;

```
const nativeElement = fixture.nativeElement;
console.log(nativeElement);
```

Edit: I am not entirely sure what the directive's class name is (maybe NgBPanelContent) but ensure that you have it in your declarations array so the HTML will know how to paint it when it sees that directive.

Comment: unfortunately, no. When logging the entire native element, the `ngbAccordion` is there, but my content is not. When viewing the page outside of the test environment, it of course shows.

Comment: Maybe you need to include the `ngbPanelContent` directive in your declarations. I see you have imported it but I am thinking it doesn't know how to paint itself.

Comment: thats it! maybe you could edit your answer and then I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you need to wait for the rendering;

```
// async added here
it('should find my element', async () => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LoginComponent);

    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
    // and await rendering
    await fixture.whenRenderingDone();

    const p = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.myClass')).nativeElement;
    p.id;
});
```

Comment: I already tried to wait by using `fakeAsync` and `tick(500)`... didnt help either.

Comment: It would be nice to have a stackblitz. The solution might lay in the code around the code snippets revealed in this question